# Get control from property name in viewmodel using Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I want to get a reference to the `TextBox` bound to a given property name.
I would like to do this without changing the view.
Is there a proper way to do this using Caliburn Micro?
If not, what is a "good enough" way?

```cs
public class MweViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public MweViewModel() : base()
    {
        PropertyChanged += (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            // Find control (i.e. TextBox) bound to property with name e.PropertyName
            TextBox textBox = ...
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your eventual goal? It seems like your `ViewModel` shouldn't be aware of your `View` to that extent, there may be another approach you could take. It may be that this is indeed the only solution to your problem, but it's definitely worth exploring what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm a WPF beginner so this might very well be the wrong approach. The idea is to provide automatic validation for attribute tagged properties in an inheriting viewmodel without having to adapt the view. Setting up the automatic validation is relatively straight forward. What I'm having problems with is controlling exactly how it behaves. My idea was to have access to view events mapped to property changes (via the `TextBox`). I.e. if someone does this in the view, validate that field.

Comment: Ah I see, presumably you'll still need to define how those errors will be displayed in your view? This might have some helpful info: http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/ Then again, it might not =D

Comment: @Chris Yes, if you want to customize the error display you'd change the Validation.ErrorTemplate in the view. There's also a reasonable red border default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not necessarily sure this is the most sensible approach (it's not something I've tried to do myself), looking at the [Documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions), there's the mention of a `ViewModelBinder` class that's responsible for fixing up the various bindings of properties, methods, etc. to their respective `ViewModels`.

The `BindProperties` function on the `ViewModelBinder` is responsible for resolving the bindings between your properties, and the UI elements to which they're eventually bound. You could, define your own function based on the existing code, which kept track of all the bindings being established, so you would have a record of them you could use elsewhere in your program.

Using the [existing code](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ViewModelBinder.cs) would give you something like this:

```
ViewModelBinder.BindProperties = (namedElements, viewModelType) =>
    {
        var unmatchedElements = new List<FrameworkElement>();

        foreach (var element in namedElements)
        {
            var cleanName = element.Name.Trim('_');
            var parts = cleanName.Split(new[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var property = viewModelType.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(parts[0]);
            var interpretedViewModelType = viewModelType;

            for (int i = 1; i < parts.Length && property != null; i++)
            {
                interpretedViewModelType = property.PropertyType;
                property = interpretedViewModelType.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(parts[i]);
            }

            if (property == null)
            {
                unmatchedElements.Add(element);
                // Log.Info("Binding Convention Not Applied: Element {0} did not match a property.", element.Name);
                continue;
            }

            var convention = ConventionManager.GetElementConvention(element.GetType());
            if (convention == null)
            {
                unmatchedElements.Add(element);
                // Log.Warn("Binding Convention Not Applied: No conventions configured for {0}.", element.GetType());
                continue;
            }

            var applied = convention.ApplyBinding(
                interpretedViewModelType,
                cleanName.Replace('_', '.'),
                property,
                element,
                convention
                );

            if (applied)
            {
                // Log.Info("Binding Convention Applied: Element {0}.", element.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                // Log.Info("Binding Convention Not Applied: Element {0} has existing binding.", element.Name);
                unmatchedElements.Add(element);
            }
        }

        return unmatchedElements;
    };
```

At the point when the binding is being added (when `applied` is set), you have all the information you require. You could then store specific bindings (e.g those relating to a `TextBox`).

You might use something like a static dictionary (there may be something far more appropriate depending on your requirement):

```
        ViewModel Type    Bound Property      List of Bound elements
             |                   |                      |
             |                   |                      |
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<PropertyInfo, List<FrameworkElement>>>
```

You would have to be careful about null/sanity checks.

There are a few other solutions that use helper methods to grab the bound properties/controls, although they often have to traverse the visual tree, this way, you're doing it at the point the binding is actually created.